# Magento mobile app (Flutter) checkout using website

Tags: magento, flutter, webview, checkout

I have a Flutter Fluxstore app.
Web application is developed in **Magento 2.**
My website payment gateway is not supported by Flux store.

So, now I want to do checkout process using the website (by loading checkout web URL in Web View).
So here I need a solution for this **how-to pass current user session to checkout page and load user cart and checkout stuff** to the current logged in user?

Can you please help me on this.